# trying to install packages on node but getting a certification error

Tags: javascript, node.js

Essentially every time I try to do `npm i (package)`, I get the error URL failed, reason: self signed certificate in certificate chain. How do I fix this issue so that I can install the packages?

I have tried different packages, and checked the URL given.

Logs are below:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-
cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'express',
1 verbose cli   '--save' ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v10.16.0
4 verbose npm-session 5a0209091f1c9b93
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for express@latest request to
https://registry.npmjs.org/express failed, reason: self signed
certificate in certificate chain
8 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
9 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 153ms
10 verbose type system
11 verbose stack FetchError: request to
https://registry.npmjs.org/express failed, reason: self signed
certificate in certificate chain
11 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.req.on.err (C:\Program
Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-
npm\src\index.js:68:14)
11 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:198:13)
11 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener
(_http_client.js:392:9)
11 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
11 verbose stack     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
11 verbose stack     at emitErrorAndCloseNT
(internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
11 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback
(internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
12 verbose cwd C:\Users\bsoong\Desktop\MapEvent
13 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.16299
14 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program
Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "express" "-
-save"
15 verbose node v10.16.0
16 verbose npm  v6.9.0
17 error code SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
18 error errno SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
19 error request to https://registry.npmjs.org/express failed, reason: self signed certificate in certificate chain
20 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade npm by:

`npm install npm -g --ca=""`

-- OR --

Tell npm to use known registrars by:

`npm config set ca ""`

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall Node.js. Then:

```
npm config set ca ""
```